# Pi 3 cannot see Ubuntu hotspot Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I want to connect my pi3 wirelessly, for that i need a hotspot wifi. But hotspot should be on laptop which is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. When i try to scan all wifi on Pi it can see only Windows-Android etc. I tried all channels to make Pi can see the Ubuntu's wifi, but Pi still cannot see Wi-Fi Hotspot on Ubuntu(btw other devices can see Ubuntu's Wi-Fi). I already can use 12-13 when i check wlan0 channels. (I already set wifi country IE on raspi-config)

Could you help me please to figure this problem ?

Edit: with same laptop on windows 10 hotspot option can visible on Pi3 as well.

Comment: In the desktop or with a command to scan the wifi ?

Comment: Which flavour of 802.1 (b, g, n, etc.) are you using on the Pi and on the Ubuntu access point?

Comment: @Jot in the command line.

Comment: @Curt J. Sampson how can i check that ?

Comment: I guess something wrong on subnet "10.42.0.0". Somehow Pi doesn't recognize it.